# How to disable automatic Karma tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, karma-runner

I have created a new Angular 2 web site. Now when I open this web site with Visual Studio 2015 (not VS Code) I see in the output window that Karma is continuously running all the tests it finds in the node_modules folder. I do not want to execute any automatic tests on code that I have not written. How can I switch this off?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **'Tools > Extensions and Updates > Installed > All'**, find **'Karma Test Adapter'**, **disable this extension** and restart Visual studio

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the Karma Test Adapter completely then use @nihique answer. However, if you still want to use Karma for your tests but do not want it to run automatically then add/update these settings in [Karma's configuration file](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html), specifically `autoWatch`.

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // This is set to true by default
    autoWatch: false,
    //...
  });
};
```

Additionally, you can set `exclude` directories/files using [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) patterns.

```
exclude: [
    // All files with "js" extension in all sub-directories
    '**/*.js',

    // Same as above, but excludes "jquery.js"
    '**/!(jquery).js',

    // In all sub-directories, all "min.js" and "spec.js" files
    '**/(min|spec).js'
]
```